# Hammer.js setting time using domEevents

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I have following code to bind pressup event on dynamically added elements:

```
$('#grid').hammer({time: 2000, domEvents: true}).on('pressup', 'tr', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

But anytime I set for time option (1000, 2000, 5000), the event fires always after the same amount of time, the default one, I think - I'm not able to measure milliseconds ;)

What do I am missing, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well. It looks nobody knows. So, the only workaround is to edit the source file changint the time option for the involved event to the desired value.
Cheers